# Retrieve those contacts from phonebook that has facebook

Tags: android

*I want to retrive all the contact from phone book that has facebook account.*

Steps i did

1. I got contact id from Contacts.
2. Based on id get Accounts from RawContact table.
3. All account associated with contact found but facebook account not found.

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow below algorithm to get contacts with specific account type.**
1. First, query on raw contacts table and find all raw contacts. Check what are different Account type and Account name are available. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#ACCOUNT_TYPE
Facebook contact will have account type with text "facebook" in it.
2. Once you got exact account type, you can query on raw contacts with account type = facebook.
3. This will give all Facebook raw contacts. Raw contact table has contact_id field using which you can query on Contacts table to get all Facebook contacts.

Below is the code snippet which can print all account names and types which are currently configured on device for which contacts are present. This is just Sample code to check what all account types are there. If you don't find any account name/type related to facebook, I guess there are no facebook contacts present.

```
String[] projection = { RawContacts._ID, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME };
        Cursor cur = cr.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
                null);
        if (cur != null) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                long rawContactId = cur.getLong(cur
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(RawContacts._ID));
                String accountType = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
                String accountName = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME));
            }
        }
```

Comment: but when query Raw contact table, i am not able to get facebook in either account type or account name field.

so how to get these details.

will you share me code snippet for  that.

Comment: Yes it works for me. If no facebook account found, it means there are no Facebook contacts available. Please check in Facebook application whether Contact Sync is on or not. I strongly suspect that there is no facebook contact in your device. You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccounts() to get all accounts configured on device. account. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html object will give you account name and type.

Comment: i have already sync my code, and also i see facebook synced with contact. it showing in connections in contact. Can you share your complete code so that i can  try with better way.